# Manifest.mf: reference Main-class in jar file

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I am making a runnable jar where my main class is eclipse's JarRsrcLoader.

This is my **Package Structure**:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

And my **Manifest**:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar
Class-Path: . 
Rsrc-Main-Class: test.Main
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

And the directory structure within my jar:

[image]

When I try to run the jar from command line using:

```
java -jar output.jar
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? When i put the `org` folder in the same directory as `output.jar`, it runs fine. I want it to be found from within the jar so that there are no external dependencies. Thanks

**UPDATE**

the classfile is in the jar:

[image]

Comment: confuse between org and output.jar.where is org folder ?

Comment: Did you verify that the file org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarRsrcLoader.**class** in your output.jar exists?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind the file is present, see update.

Comment: @NiksTyagi org folder is in output.jar. when I moved it to the same directory as the jar, the jar runs. I want it to run when everything is contained within the jar.

Comment: What is the output of `java -version` and what source code level are you using in Eclipse?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly both are jdk 1.7.0_40

Comment: How about ditching `JarRsrcLoader` all-together? Just move the `selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar` to an external `lib` folder next to `output.jar`, update `Class-Path` to `lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar`, `Main-Class` to `test.Main` and remove both `Rsrc-Class-Path` and `Rsrc-Main-Class:` (as well as the `org` folder). Go standard!

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly I had that working already but I would prefer if everything was in one jar. Is it possible?

Comment: As strange as it may sound (or maybe not?), rebooting the computer did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Though this was asked long time back, this is what worked for me

Try creating a package in your workspace like com.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader and place all the files JarRsrcLoader.java, RsrcURLConnection.java , RsrcURLStreamHandler.java and RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory.java which can be downloaded from google.
Then wrote the Manifest as shown

```
 Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_55
    Class-Path: .
    Rsrc-Main-Class: com.abc.Master
    Main-Class: com.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
    Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ lib/xyz.jar
```

Comment: I also liked this solution. But: can you automate it with maven?

Comment: @user1414745 I think maven shade plugin would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of several other Uber jar tools:

- [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)
- [Fat Jar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/)
- [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice)
- [Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) (Maven)